# Generar lista de palabras sumando elementos de listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucles

Como puedo generar una lista de palabras sumando varias listas por posiciones
pero que al hacerlo, sean todas las combinaciones posibles.

```
I = ('iI1!¡')
S = ('sS5')
A = ('aA4')
b = ('bB8')
e = ('Ee3')
L = ('1Ll¡!')

for i in I:
    for s in S:
        for a in A:
            for b in B:
                for e in E:
                    for l in L:
                        for a2 in A:
                            print(i+s+a+b+e+l+a2)
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No se ve ninguna lista en el código ...

Comment: Entonces, tupla o string

Answer (score 1):

El ćodigo original no contiene ninguna lista, ni tuplas. Pensando que lo que quieres es obtener el próducto cartesiano a partir de varios iterables, en donde cada posición del iterable contiene un carácter, la solución sería a través la función `product` en `itertools`.

```py
from itertools import product

a = '1234'
b = '5678'
c = 'ABCD'
d = 'EFGH'

print(list(''.join(e) for e in product(a, b, c, d)))
```

La función `product` hablando estrictamente, es un [generador](https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/11/iteradores-y-generadores.html), es decir que su comportamiento de generar un solo elemento le permite ser eficiente en términos de consumo de memoria. Cada elemento arrojado por el generador `product` es una tupla que contiene los elementos combinados. Para convertir dicha tupla en una cadena es que se hace uso de `join`.

> **Nota.** La conversión a una lista es solo para hacer visible el resultado al momento de hacer el print, no hagas la conversión de un generador a una lista a menos que sea realmente necesario.

Comment: Gracias por responder, no es lo que estaba pensando, pero ha sido muy interesante.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar las combinaciones anidando ciclos `for`.

Para generar un número bajo de combinaciones, he reducido a 2 símbolos cada caracter, entre otros ajustes menores. Dado que entiendo que la pregunta era más sobre como conseguir las combinaciones, imprimo el resultado, agregar elementos a una lista supongo que te resultará trivial:

```
I = ('i1')
S = ('s5')
A = ('a4')
B = ('b8')
E = ('e3')
L = ('L¡')

for i in I:
    for s in S:
        for a in A:
            for b in B:
                for e in E:
                    for l in L:
                        for a2 in A:
                            print(i+s+a+b+e+l+a2)
```

Comment: La lista generada tiene todas las posibles combinaciones en ese sentido?

Comment: si, todas las combinaciones